# File read from a site's response doesn't completely match the actual file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, byte

When trying to read a zip file's contents into a variable (using javascript & ajax),
I get less bytes than when downloading the file.

For example: the file size is 573 bytes, but the variable's length after reading the contents  will be 564.

This is my request code:

```
getRequest : function(Url, params, _success, _error) {
        var Url = Url;
        var paramsString = this.encodeParams(params);
        if (ParamsString != "") {
            Url = Url + "?" + ParamsString;
        }
        var RequestHeaders = this.getHeaders();

        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : Url,
            headers : RequestHeaders,
            success : function(data, textStatus) {
                _success(data);
            },
        error : function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            _error(jqxhr.responseText);
            }
    });
}
```

Saving to a variable:

```
getRequest(url,{},
    function(data){zipContents=data},
    function(data){alert(data)});
```

Would appreciate any help in finding out why this happens.

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you save the file you have loaded in memory?  Its an interesting question, since 10 bytes is not much data im guessing there may be some meta data associated with the file in windows which is not getting read in when you load the file in your application

Comment: Could there be some difference in line break characters?

Comment: @Purplegoldfish - When I save it to memory I get the correct byte count.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I think the servers are based on linux and I download to a windows. Do you think I should try downloading the file to a linux based machine and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: When downloading the file to a linux machine, the file size is 573, same as in Windows...

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to do some sniffing on the HTTP requests. The Network tab in Chrome's inspector is useful for that.
In particular, check the `Content-Length` header that the server returns. Does it say 573 or 564 bytes?
Also check the `Content-Type` header - it should be `application/zip`.

If you find a mismatch in any of these values, it is probably the server that needs configuring. Have you tried moving your files to another server?